Multiple cavities in a conductor and a charge outside
So I came across this problem:

A spherical conductor 'A' contains  two spherical cavities as shown in figure. The net charge on conductor itself is zero. However, there is a point charge $q_{1}$ at the center of one cavity and $q_{2}$ at the center of the other cavity. Another charge $q_{3}$ is
placed at a large distance r from the center of the spherical conductor. Compare the forces exerted by $q_3$ on $q_1$ and $q_2$.
Figure:


Let the induced charge on outer surface be denoted by $q_4$. We know $q_4=q_1+q_2$.
Let the electric field due to $q_4$ at $q_1$'s position be $\vec{E_4}$
Let the electric field due to $q_3$ at $q_1$'s position be $\vec{E_3}$
Let the net electric field at $q_1$'s position be $\vec{E}$
So what I thought was that $q_3$ will exert a greater force on $q_2$ since the distance between $q_2$ and $q_3$ is lesser than that between $q_3$ and $q_1$.
However the book says $\vec{E_3}= \vec{E_4}=0$ Hence $q_3$ exerts no force on either $q_1$ or $q_2$. But I think that just plainly disobeys Coulombs law.
I know that for any point inside a cavity, the NET electric field due to all the charges outside is zero i.e. $\vec{E}=0$. But is that true for $\vec{E_3}$ and $\vec{E_4}$ individually, or is it that the individual fields are non zero, and the fields due to $q_4$ and $q_3$ are equal and opposite and cancel each other out?
I was under the impression that $\vec{E_4} =-\vec{E_3}$, but $\vec{E_i} \neq 0$ (where i=3,4)
So which is the correct statement?

You are right that $\vec E_4=-\vec E_3$ but neither of them is zero.
If the book says $\vec E_4=\vec E_3=0$, then the book is wrong (unless it defines $\vec E_3$ and $\vec E_4$ differently than you do in your description, so without a reference we cannot be completely sure...)
